# In-place upgrade of Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

Is there any way to do an in-place upgrade from Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 7 Enterprise? I get an error saying that there's a compatibility issue, but perhaps there's some way to modify the registry to bypass this restriction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a registry edit to do it:

`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\`

`HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`

Change where it says Ultimate to Enterprise

Once you have done that load the Windows 7 Enterprise CD and do the upgrade install - **Without UPDATES** - and everything works just fine.

Once installed go to Disk Cleanup and do: Clean up system files - **Previous Windows installations**

Answer (score 2):

No, this scenario is not supported by Microsoft.

Here is Microsoft's official list of supported upgrades:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772579(WS.10).aspx

*note:* this would technically be a downgrade rather than an upgrade

Comment: I realize that. That's why I wanted to know if there was a way to bypass the restriction by modifying the registry.